# ExtJS 4 - rounded corner for textfield not working

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a textfield defined below as such:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
x: 490,
y: 365,
cls: 'textarea',
height: 40,
width: 300,
fieldLabel: 'Label',
hideEmptyLabel: false,
hideLabel: true
```

And my CSS is defined as such:

```
.textarea {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

However, the textfield still has corners. I think I'm doing something wrong and I can't spot it out. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:-

```
.textarea .x-form-text {
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

You need to provide border radius property to the `<input>` element, but you were trying to set it to component element which contains the `<input>` element.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also try `fieldStyle`:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    x: 490,
    y: 365,
    cls: 'textarea',
    height: 40,
    width: 300,
    fieldLabel: 'Label',
    hideEmptyLabel: false,
    hideLabel: true,
    fieldStyle: {
        borderRadius: 5 //here
    }
}
```

of course, this will only apply to the component you created. but if you want to make this affect all fields with `textarea` cls, try using `fieldCls` instead.